# Why do I get the error "File cannot be resolved to a type"?

Tags: java

Here's part of my code

```
try{

    BufferedReader in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    while ((line= in.readLine())!="exit"){

    System.out.println("Enter command");
    line=in.readLine();
    Command currentCommand=new Command(line);



    File currentFile= new File(currentCommand.getLsPath());
```

The method `currentCommand.getLsPath()` returns a string, which is mendatory for the File Constracture, and still I get this error: `File cannot be resolved to a type`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 18):

Chances are you've just missed:

```
import java.io.File;
```

from the top of your source file.

You *could* use

```
 import java.io.*;
```

I typically use single-type imports.

Answer (score 6):

You need to include either

```
import java.io.File;
```

or

```
import java.io.*;
```

at the top of your source file.

Comment: Jon Skeet beat me by 12 seconds. There is no dishonor in that :)

Comment: So wierd, so why It does not notify me about that as any other package?

Comment: You should need to import `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader`. The `Command` class may be local to your application, and the `System` class is automatically imported, like everything else in the `java.lang` package.

Comment: These I imported, but when I forgot to do that, I got a notifaction suggesting me ti import them, unlike this one.

Comment: @Unknown user: When I tried with `BufferedReader` I got exactly the same error as for `File`.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely forgot to import java.io.File but essentially the compiler is telling you it can't find the "File" class.

See this java error page specific to "[File cannot be resovled to a type](http://java.syntaxerrors.info/index.php?title=Cannot_resolve_type)" for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error once, even though I had already imported java.io.File. I think it was some weird, temporary Eclsipse glitch. When I made other changes to the code, then saved it again, the error resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

i also got that error and by giving try catch block just before creating object of FileReader , FileWriter not before creating a variable of type FileReader or FileWriter could resolve that issue and just make sure to close the
resource .

Comment: I don't think so. The solution for the type 'File' not being defined is to define it (via an import statement).