# File cannot be resolved to a type Blackberry

Tags: parsing, blackberry

I m trying to access to the content of an xml file.
I used docBuilder to parse the file which is stored on /res.

```
             Document xml = docBuilder.parse(new File("test.xml"));
```

but I'm getting this error "File cannot be resolved to a type."
I tried to add an external archieve but I don't know wich .zip or .jar I had to add.

Comment: Did you import java.io.File? Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996989/why-do-i-get-the-error-file-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type. This link is helpful also, http://java.syntaxerrors.info/index.php?title=Cannot_resolve_type.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, but I've already imported it but in vain. I think Ihave to create the class file.