# Getting error File cannot be resolved to a type for java in visual studio code

Tags: java, visual-studio-2010

I am using 1 main class and 1 interface and attached my pseudo code for lambda expressions:

Below is how it looks like:

[image]

Below is simple interface:

[image]

I am not doing any IO operations so
[Why do I get the error "File cannot be resolved to a type"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996989/why-do-i-get-the-error-file-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type)

does not help me.Tried few more options like clean build project. restarting vs code but not helping. Looking for suggestions to fix this java 8 error. Doing java 8 for first time.

Comment: My Project folder src is already in the project source path.

Comment: You didn't `import java.io.File`.

Comment: I imported java.io.File early but still same error.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Its very strange but i cleaned and build workspace again and did restart of visual studio code 2nd time.  Error is gone now without importing java.io.File.

This seems really weird. I had such situations in old days when i used eclipse IDE.

I did Ctrl+Shift+P(Command Pallete) -> Clean Java server language workspace-> Restart and delete.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My Source code does not contain any file operations so
importing java.io.file was not helping me.

I did Ctrl+Shift+P(Command Pallete) -> Clean Java server language workspace-> Restart and delete.

This solved the error. Its quite weird that Visual studio code sometimes not build workspace properly. I assumed earlier that it happens only with eclipse old versions but it do happens with new vs code editors as well.